# Sort an array by a numeric value in each entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Say I had an array like this:

```json
[{"Platinum":13},{"Bronze":2910},{"Diamond":92},{"Gold":346},{"Silver":649},{"Stone":12561}]
```

How would I be able to sort them so they organize themselves from largest to smallest by the number:

```json
[{"Stone":12561},{"Bronze":2910},{"Silver":649},{"Gold":346},{"Bronze":2910},{"Diamond":92},{"Platinum":13}]
```

Any answer is appreciated, I'm completely stuck on this.

Comment: Note there is no JSON involved here. JSON is a text format.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [{"Platinum":13},{"Bronze":2910},{"Diamond":92},{"Gold":346},{"Silver":649},{"Stone":12561}]

arr.sort((a,b) => Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0])

console.log(arr)
```